# How to resolve exception when uploading file to SharePoint using List.RootFolder.Files.Add (C#)

Tags: c#, sharepoint, file-upload, sharepoint-clientobject

Context: I am trying to upload a large number of files to a SharePoint library. I will call the library `Library Name` here.
For simplicity, I will only be attempting to upload one file in the code that follows. The path to this file will be `C:/Users/UserName/Desktop/Test.txt`
I will call the SharePoint Site `http://share-internal.CompanyName.com/Section/Subsection`

Here is the code I am using:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;

namespace FilesToSharePointLibrary
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String fileToUpload = "C:/Users/UserName/Desktop/Test.txt";
            String sharePointSite = "http://share-internal.CompanyName.com/Section/Subsection"; 
            String libraryName = "Library Name";
            String fileName = fileToUpload.Substring(fileToUpload.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
            using(ClientContext context = new ClientContext(sharePointSite))
            {
                FileCreationInformation FCInfo = new FileCreationInformation();
                FCInfo.Url = fileToUpload;
                FCInfo.Overwrite = true;
                FCInfo.Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileToUpload);

                Web web = context.Web;
                List library = web.Lists.GetByTitle(libraryName);
                library.RootFolder.Files.Add(FCInfo);
                context.ExecuteQuery();

            }
            Console.WriteLine("Success");
        }
    }
}
```

The issue I am having in the `context.ExecuteQuery();` line.
When I attempt to add one file to the SharePoint Library, `Library Name` I get the following Exception:
`Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException: 'Value does not fall within the expected range.'`

Things I have tried:

- I tried using different versions of the URL to the SharePoint Site I'm using. The URL I am currently using is the correct URL.
- I have made sure that I have the library name correct. I tried using looking for `Library_x0020_Name`, but the exception changed, saying it could not find that list.

This leads me to believe that I have the list name and site URL correct, So I am confused as to what could be causing issues at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use SharePoint library folder url when setting FCInfo.Url property, I modify the code snippet below to upload to the default SharePoint Library named "Documents":

```
            String fileToUpload = "C:/Users/Administrator.CONTOSO2016/Desktop/Test.txt";
            String sharePointSite = "http://sp2016/sites/dev/";
            String libraryName = "Documents";
            String fileName = fileToUpload.Substring(fileToUpload.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
            using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext(sharePointSite))
            {
                FileCreationInformation FCInfo = new FileCreationInformation();
                FCInfo.Url = "http://sp2016/sites/dev/Shared%20Documents/Test.txt";
                FCInfo.Overwrite = true;
                FCInfo.Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileToUpload);

                Web web = context.Web;
                List library = web.Lists.GetByTitle(libraryName);
                Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File uploadfile = library.RootFolder.Files.Add(FCInfo);
                uploadfile.CheckIn("testcomment",CheckinType.MajorCheckIn);
                context.ExecuteQuery();

            }
            Console.WriteLine("Success");
```

[image]